# specified try except with datetime.date()

Tags: python, exception

I am trying to catch the exceptions with incorrect month and days and negative years of date() from the datetime module but when I use ValueError exception I can't be specific. How can I specify my exceptions?

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta



a = int(input('Year:'))
b = int(input('Month:'))
c = int(input('Day:'))

try:
    a_date = date(a, b, c)
    print(a_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
except ValueError:
    print('month must be in 1..12')
```

Comment: If you need something more specific, you should do your own validation rather than depending on the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot distinguish the exception *type*, since the `datetime` library uses `ValueError` for all value error conditions on `date()` object creation.
What you can do, is either print the error message from the value error itself or inspect the value error's string.

```py
try:
    a_date = date(a, b, c)
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
```

```py
try:
    a_date = date(a, b, c)
except ValueError as error:
    if 'month' in str(error):
        print('Invalid month')
    ...
```